# Norm and Multiplication

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

If $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $0 \leq C_{i,j} \leq 1$, $A_{i,j},B_{i,j} \geq 0$, and $||A||_F \leq ||B||_F$, then $||C \cdot A||_F \leq ||C \cdot B||_F$ where "$\cdot$" is pairwise product.

Is it true or not?

Comment: note that $||.||_F$ is frobenius

Answer (score 0):

This statement is false. Let A, B, and C be the following.

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    0.03219379       & 0.63947916  \\
    0.29375581       & 0.98938686 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
    0.64079509       & 0.87661346  \\
    0.76240589       & 0.21987217 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
    0.00205744       & 0.08024417  \\
    0.14910081       & 0.33285072 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then $||A||_F = 1.215$ and $||B||_F = 1.345$, so that $||A||_F \leq ||B||_F$, but $||C\cdot A||_F = 0.336$ and $||C\cdot B||_F = 0.152$, so that $||C\cdot A||_F > ||C\cdot B||_F$, where $X\cdot Y$ denotes the pairwise/element-wise multiplication.